# Access the Remote Access Preferences properties

Tags: windows-7, control-panel

How can I access the *Remote Access Preferences* properties on Windows 7 SP1 without having to wait for a VPN connection to fail?

[image: Remote_Access_Preferences]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly explained in this Microsoft TechNet article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732434%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

> 1. Open the Network Connections folder and view available connections.
> 2. Press ALT to display the menu bar.
> 3. On the Advanced menu, click Remote Access Preferences.